# trigger function on tab change in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have site with tabs that contain some data. The `$scope` is changed to `vm` in the controller. I want to execute a function every time the tab is changed.I have tried `ng-change`, but that only lead to errors in angular.
So I did read some postings here and found the `ngModel` method. But this does not work either. I always get a `Error: String contains an invalid character` from `angular.min.js` .

```
<b2b-tabset tab-id-selected="vm.activeTabsId" ng-if="vm.selectedUserID" [ngModel]="vm.activeTabsId" (ngModelChange)="vm.changeTab()" >
    <b2b-tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.gTabs" tab-item="tab" id="{{tab.uniqueId}}" aria-controls="{{tab.tabPanelId}}" ng-disabled="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.title}}
    </b2b-tab>
</b2b-tabset>
<div class="tab-content">
....
</div>
```

As following the comments i changed the code to this. That did not throw an error, but did not work also:

```
<b2b-tabset tab-id-selected="vm.activeTabsId" ng-if="vm.selectedUserID" ng-model="vm.activeTabsId" ng-change="vm.changeTab()" >
    <b2b-tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.gTabs" tab-item="tab" id="{{tab.uniqueId}}" aria-controls="{{tab.tabPanelId}}" ng-disabled="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.title}}
    </b2b-tab>
</b2b-tabset>
```

I am using a route file like this:

```
appDS2.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/users', {
    templateUrl: 'app/abcd/scripts/DS2-view-models/user.html',
    controller : 'UserController as vm'
})
```

Comment: You are mixing angular 1.x and angular 2. [ngModel] is for angular to while all other your directives are of angular 1.x

Comment: So is there a similar functionality in angular 1.x ?

Comment: so which angular you are using 1.x or angular 2?

Comment: I have to use angular 1.x as i can not change the environment

Comment: You can use ng-model and $scope.$watch to watch the ng-model variable

Comment: Try using ng-model and ng-change directives. `ng-model="vm.activeTabsId" ng-change="vm.changeTab()"`. Are you using ControllerAs syntax btw?

Comment: so changing to this does not throw any error, but doe snot work also:   <pre><b2b-tabset tab-id-selected="vm.activeTabsId" ng-if="vm.selectedFirewallID" ng-model="vm.activeTabsId" ng-change="vm.changeTab()" > <code>
        <b2b-tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.gTabs" tab-item="tab" id="{{tab.uniqueId}}" aria-controls="{{tab.tabPanelId}}" ng-disabled="tab.disabled">
            {{tab.title}}
        </b2b-tab>
    </b2b-tabset>

Comment: @ Aliaksandr Bortnik I am not using the controlAs directive, i use routeProvider to define the controller per page.